# How to filter default product list in the admin side WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

- I've created a custom post type called "products". Also, I've created categories for the product post type.
- All works perfectly but in the admin side products listing I want to show only that product that has an "Active category".
- I've created custom functionality the make the categories active and inactive.
- I need to show only that product that has an active category in the edit page listing.
  Here:[image]

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.